# Is the available db2 express on IBM is similar as DB2 for IBM i (db2/as400) green screen uses?

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange, legacy, legacy-database

basically. I'm trying to develop a PHP app that requires an access to DB2 for IBM i (db2/as400) database. However, I'm not much familiar with DB2 for IBM i (db2/as400) environment, so I'm doing research.

I'm planning to install db2 express i found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html) on my dev laptop hoping i could emulate that one from our client's server environment. Would it be the same? or should i download another one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL differences for DB2 versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146051/sql-differences-for-db2-versions)

Comment: I think you've done the right thing.  You'd be connecting with a connection string there will be some tweaking to do.

Comment: thanks guys. i guess i'll continue on downloading db2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three major DB2 platforms (z/OS, i, and LUW) share enough common SQL syntax to make cross-platform application development an approachable goal. It's worth pointing out that the current edition of IBM's [SQL Reference for Cross-Platform
Development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0206sqlref/0206sqlref.html) contains over a thousand pages.

[IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/), a no-cost IDE based on Eclipse, is capable of running SQL statements, browsing database objects, and developing stored procedures on every DB2 platform. It is a separate download from DB2 servers and clients.

Unlike cross-platform DML, which is largely identical, an application's underlying DDL could differ considerably between DB2 for i and DB2 LUW, the platform/family to which DB2 Express-C belongs.

Cross-platform DB2 connectivity is most easily accomplished via IBM's JDBC Type 4 driver, but it might not be practical for PHP. Accessing DB2 for i (and z/OS) over other protocols requires an extra piece of software called [DB2 Connect](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2-connect-family/).